# render image while play the video using Opengl android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, record

I want to overlay/embed the image on the recorded video. 
I have done overlay the image/colorbox on the camera recording.
But if any help if i render any color or image on recorded video ??

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read overlayed frames back from GPU in a image and then encode such obtained frames. You can perform `RTT(Render to Texture)` then read back that texture on CPU. I am not sure how to read back exactly on android platform. But this is the direction in which you should investigate.